# Firebase Unity xCode linking errors

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, firebase, sdk

I am having issues trying to make a build from Unity (version 5.5.2f1) with Firebase Auth / Database imported. I am using the newest Firebase SDK of 3.0.0.

The errors I get are as follows:

[image: Screenshot]

I believe it has something to do with cocoaPods. The XCode project compiles with a podfile. And the errors I believe are related to missing libraries? But all the required libraries are set to iOS, and are included with the XCode project.

Unsure of what to try next. Thanks in advance to anyone able to help.

Comment: I believe the image is showing correctly now?

Comment: are you opening the .xcodeproj or .xcworkspace ?

Comment: Hey Scott, I am opening the .xcworkspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out my issue. I had a previous build that worked all the way through to my device. So I eventually tried opening that one again, and I ran into the same errors with an older build.

So that got me thinking.. Why would a previous build that used to work fail this time around?

I came to the conclusion that the only things that changed were possibly me updated Unity to 5.5.2f1. So I updated again to the latest release at this time which is 5.5.2p3, and ran through the same steps:

1) Build to iOS
2) Install pods in the target folder
3) Run xc workspace

And it successfully built. So it must of been something on Unity's side. If anyone ever runs into a similar situation, hopefully this will help.

P.S. I also did update to the latest release (at this time) of Unity Firebase SDK of 3.0.1. Not sure if that had anything to do with making a successful build, but wanted to put that information out there.

Answer (score 0):

When you build and run from within unity, it tries to run the pod installation for the dependencies needed, and patches the xcode project file (not workspace).

If there is an error with this process, you should see it in the console.

Normally pods are meant to be used with the workspace file, but since unity automatically opens the xcode project the plugin tries to make it work.

Try opening the .xcodeproj instead of the workspace.

Comment: I have tried opening the .xcodeproj as well. I get the same linking errors with either project. That's what's throwing me off completely.